# "table doesn't exist" -error trying to query database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

With Xamarin forms I want to display information from a database in a `ListView`. There are two tables in the SQLite database.

1. I created an override of `OnAppearing` so the data would show up once the page appears.
2. Inside that I opened an SQLite connection:

   ```
    using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
    {
      //about to put the code here in the next step
    }
   ```
3. Inside that I create the table (`<ModelName>` is the name of class that holds the model) :

   ```
    conn.CreateTable<ModelName>
   ```
4. Then use a query and set that as `ItemSource` for `ListView`:

   ```
    ListViewName.ItemSource = conn.Query<ModelName>("SELECT * FROM databaseTableName;");
   ```
5. On front end set data binding :

   ```
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewName">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding ModelName}" Detail="{Binding ModelName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
   ```

I also tried setting binding like :

```
Text="{Binding ColumnNameFromTable}"
```

Error message says table doesn't exist but I have the database in assets and resources folder and the table is there. Where am I going wrong?

`(App.DatabaseLocation)` is set in MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate.cs :

```
//in MainActivity.cs
string dbName = "DatabaseName.db";
string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
```

```
//in AppDelegate.cs
string dbName = "DatabaseName.db";
string folderPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"..", "Library");
string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
```

Comment: What is App.DatabaseLocation equal to?

Comment: I've added that information to the main body of the question. I'd really appreciate you looking at it and tell me if you see where I'm going wrong

Comment: Have you tried to use directly the path as a string?            
using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("fullPath"))

Comment: I tried that. But since it is cross platform the full path string is generated differently in the android and ios project files and (ie MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate.cs) But because of that when I try to use the 'fullPath' on the searchpage.cs it doesn't know where to get it. But I can't build the string in the searchpage.cs because of the cross platform factor

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xamarin Forms, you don't need to set anything for local database in MainActivity.cs and AppDelegate.cs.
Go through this guide will explain best how to use sqllite on Xamarin Forms
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

Simple sample code can be found here:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo
This sample has retrieve data to listview like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing that:

```
public static List<string> GetClients()
{
    var clients = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Database))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "select name from YourTableName order by ID desc";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        clients.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["name"]));
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Globals.Error = ex.Message;
        clients.Clear();
    }

    return clients;
}
```

Then you do this, assuming you only need to show one column:

```
public static void UpdateClients(ListView list)
{
    list.Items.Clear();
    var listNames = GetClients(); // Call the above method
    foreach (var name in listNames)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(name);
        list.Items.Add(item);
        
        /* If you need to show more columns you might
         * want to use the SubItems.Add method for each
         * column right before the "list.Items.Add(item)"
         * line */
    }
}
```

And finally, call the method to populate the ListView:

```
private void ModifyClients_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateClients(listClients);
}
```